# having problem while "Calling Web services in android"

Tags: android, web-services

```
package com.android.project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import com.android.project.R;
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.TextView;


/*
 NOTE: You have to give this app permission to access
 the internet !!! See the AndroidManifest.xml file
 */
public class MyprojectActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://mydomain.org/SqlConnection";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "SqlConnection";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://localhost/mydomain.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://localhost:8080/WebService.asmx";
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);

        try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            //request.addProperty("prop1", "myprop");

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet=true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            Object result = (Object)envelope.getResponse();

            String[] results = (String[])  result;
            tv.setText( ""+results[0]);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            tv.setText(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am having error in (R.id.text1) ... why is that so ? i am not getting it please help asap. !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `text1` is written correctly in your layout file

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text1".....
```

for your comment

> i am having error in (R.id.text1) ... why is that so ? i am not getting it please help asap. !! – [shumaila](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339089/having-problem-while-calling-web-services-in-android/7339163#comment8851413_7339089).

Comment: hey the error has been removed. but i want to know that why do we need to do this ?

Comment: "The application MyPro(process com.android.mypro) has stopped unexpectedly please try agan. "
I got this error when i run my code on emulator ...
Solution please

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html this will tell you why , and if my answer solve ur problem vote for it and make it the right answer by check the arrow appear on the voting area

Comment: what is stack tree ? i dunt know about this

Answer (score 0):

First of all, declare your TextView tv `private`. 
Second, you need to be a little more specific with your problem? Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: error is 'id cannot be resolved and is not a field '

Comment: Make sure you have set the proper id for your textview. android:id="@+id/text1"

Comment: yeah i have set and error removed . thanks.